# SIGABRT on std::ifstream close

Tags: c++, c++20

1I am currently working on a project of creating my own game in OpenGL. My problem is right now, that if I read a file, that my function reading that file results in a SIGABRT, because of something inside the std::ifstream deconstructor (more specifically in "`std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_ifstream()`"). This function previously worked for me, but suddenly stopped working.

My Goal is simple: A reliable implementation for reading a file to a char*. Multi threading is currently not my concern.

Here is my implementation of the file reading function.
It takes in a path, and should write the content of the file at that path into the `out` parameter.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>
#include "Utility.h"
char * Utility::readFile(const char* path,char*& out){
#ifndef NDEBUG
    std::cout<<"Getting file: "<<path<<"\n";
#endif
    // Open the file, but freak out if not valid.
    std::ifstream file=std::ifstream(path);
    assert(file.good());
    if(!file.good())
    {
        throw std::runtime_error((std::string)"Couldn't open file for loading: "+path);
    }

    // Read the file contents into a char buffer.
    std::stringstream buffer;buffer << file.rdbuf();
    std::string fileContentsStr = buffer.str();
    out = new char[fileContentsStr.size()];
    strcpy(out,fileContentsStr.c_str());
    return out;
}
```

My code is located at [C0D3-M4513R/OpenGlGame](https://github.com/C0D3-M4513R/OpenGLGame).
I already tried a minimal example, which is working and using the same compile flags (except linker flags). test.txt and test1.txt just contain some rubbish text generated by randomly hacking on my keyboard.

```
#include <cassert>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

//This Function is the same as the one above!!!
char *readFile(const char *path, char *&out) {
#ifndef NDEBUG
    std::cout << "Getting file: " << path << "\n";
#endif
    // Open the file, but freak out if not valid.
    std::ifstream file = std::ifstream(path);
    assert(file.good());
    if (!file.good()) {
        throw std::runtime_error((std::string) "Couldn't open file for loading: " + path);
    }

    // Read the file contents into a char buffer.
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << file.rdbuf();
    //convert the stringstream to a string
    std::string fileContentsStr = buffer.str();
    //copy the contents of the string to a char array
    out = new char[fileContentsStr.size()];
    strcpy(out, fileContentsStr.c_str());
    //return char array address (which should be the same as the start?)
    return out;
}

int main() {
    //The programm started!
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    //Define a space for the contents of the file to live
    char *out;
    //Read the contents of a file
    out = readFile("test.txt", out);
    //Print contents of the file
    std::cout << out << std::endl;
    char *out1;
    //Read the contents of a file
    out1 = readFile("test1.txt", out1);
    //Print contents of the file
    std::cout << out1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `out = new char[fileContentsStr.size()];` why not just `return fileContentsStr` and make it return `std::string`?

Comment: Seems it would be simpler and more efficient to just return `std::string`.

Comment: That actually solved the problem. But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy):

> Copies the character string pointed to by src, **including the null terminator**, to the character array whose first element is pointed to by dest.
> **The behavior is undefined if the dest array is not large enough.** The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap.

[`c_str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str):

> Returns a pointer to a null-terminated character array with data equivalent to those stored in the string.

> ```
> out = new char[fileContentsStr.size()];
> strcpy(out,fileContentsStr.c_str());
> ```

You need to be careful when mixing `std::string` with c-strings, because a `std::string` is not null-terminated and does not count the nullterminator for its size. However, `c_str` does return a pointer to a null-terminated character array.

You are asking `strcpy` to write `fileContentsStr.size()+1` (size + null terminator) into a char array with only `fileContentsStr.size()` elements.

PS: As mentioned in a comment, you should consider to return a `std::string` instead. You are using a raw owning pointer which is error prone and should be avoided. Either use a smart-pointer or let a `std::string` manage the char-array (thats what its made for actually ;).

Comment: What do you mean by “not null-terminated”?  You *can* read (but not write!) `s[s.size()]`.

Comment: @DavisHerring `std::string`s are not null-terminated. They can have null characters in the middle without problems. `operator[ size ]` returns a reference to a null terminator, but that is not necessarily stored in the `std::string`s underlying c-string.

Comment: True, their length is not *determined* by null characters.  The terminator is contiguous with the rest of the string (since C++11, when it was guaranteed to exist at all).